# I'm trying to use checkbox as condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So what I'm trying to do is this:
The user basically chooses date with input type='date', but if the user clicks a checkbox right next to it, the input type='date' will be replaced with the current date and time. And here is the code I wrote:

```js
        function myFunction() {
            if($("#checkbox").checked == true) {
                $("#input_date").hide();
                var now = new Date();
                $("#current_datetime").text(now).show();
            } else if($("#checkbox").checked == false) {
                $("#current_datetime").hide();
                $("#input_date").show();  
            }
        }
```

In the `#checkbox` in html code, I have `onClick="myFunction"`.

As well, `#current_datetime`, which is simple text in span tag, and `#input_date` are located in the exactly same spot on the page.

But the function just won't work. There is no change at all, no matter how many times I click the checkbox.

I appreciate very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Share complete code, including HTML

Comment: i don't think so you need another text box to show current date

Comment: Share the HTML code so we know what you have done there, may be something wrong in your HTML

Answer (score 2):

You can format your date according to below then you can use it in input type='date'

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#currentDate").on('change',function(){
   var checked=$(this)[0].checked;
   console.log(checked)
   if(checked){
     var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
     today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd; 
     $("#Date").val((today))
   }
   else{
   $("#Date").val('')
   }
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='date' id='Date'/><input type='checkbox' id='currentDate'/>
```

Comment: Oh I actually have one more question. I was trying to add time (HH:MM) so added
`var hhmm = today.getTime();`
and also added this variable `hhmm` to the variable `today` below. However it doesn't work. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

hope this help you

```
<input type="date" id="input_date">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >
<p id="current_datetime"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $("#input_date").hide();
            var now = new Date();
            $("#current_datetime").text(now).show();
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $("#current_datetime").hide();
            $("#input_date").show(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked is a property, you can read the value with .prop(). Also, to change the input value you need to use .val().

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function myFunction() {
        if($("#checkbox").prop('checked') == true) {
            $("#input_date").hide();
            var now = new Date();
            $("#current_datetime").val(now).show();
        } else if($("#checkbox").prop('checked') == false) {
            $("#current_datetime").hide();
            $("#input_date").show();  
        }
    }
</script>
```